# Make a thumbnail image large when clicked using html/css3 only

Tags: html, css

I want to make an image larger on click/double click the thumbnail and then when i hover that real image it should zoom... till now i can hover a thumbnail and it showsthe real image but i want to use click (to display) and then hover the real image...i dont want to use js, isn't there any property in css3 which could help?

here is my code for this

```
    <section>
<li><a class="thumbnail" href="#">
                                            <img src="graphics/blue1.jpg" alt= "" width="100" height="150" />
                                            <span><img src="graphics/blue1.jpg"/><br /></span></a>
                                            </li>

                                            <li><a class="thumbnail" href="#">
                                            <img src="graphics/blue2.jpg" alt="" width="100" height="150" />
                                            <span><img src="graphics/blue2.jpg" /></span></a>
                                            </li>
                                            <li>
                                            <a class="thumbnail" href="#"><img src="graphics/blue3.jpg" alt="" width="100" height="150" />
                                            <span><img src="graphics/blue3.jpg"/><br /></span></a>
                                            </li>


                        </section>
```

here is css for these thumbnails

```
 section li {
                list-style:none;
                    }

.thumbnail{
position: relative;
z-index: 0;
}

.thumbnail:hover{
background-color: transparent;
z-index: 50;
}

.thumbnail span{ /*CSS for enlarged image*/
position: absolute;
background-color:#eee;
padding:5px;
left: -1000px;
border: 1px dashed gray;
visibility: hidden;
color: black;
text-decoration: none;
}

.thumbnail span img{ 
border-width: 0;
padding: 1px;
}

.thumbnail:hover span{ 
visibility: visible;
top: 10px;
left: 120px; 
}
```

also on the mouse hover the hover image goes down instead of coming infront in front..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To Trigger click events in css, you should do the following:
encapsulate your image in `<a>`

```
<a href="#ImgToDisplay"><img id="imageToBeClickedOn"/></a>

<img id="ImgToDisplay"></img>
```

Set ImgToDisplay on hide by default and add the following in your css:

```
ImgToDisplay:target
{
//set your image to visible here.
}
```

Moreover to enlarge ImgToDisplay on hover, just:

```
ImgToDisplay:hover
{
//enlarge your image here
}
```

Comment: thanx for ur help, but its not working with my code...from the code i have posted, can you please correct the position of the hoovered image?? its n ot coming in front of the thumbnail instead it goes down infront of the other thumbnail..thanx again

Comment: You have made your '.thumbnail span absolute', so you're going to have to position it very carefully.
The problem lies in your:
'.thumbnail:hover span{ 
visibility: visible;
top: 10px;
left: 120px;
}'
Adjust 'left' in the above css to position your new image the way you want.

Comment: By the way, see the following link: http://tangledindesign.com/how-to-trigger-css3-transitions-on-click-using-target/

for your previous problem. Let me know if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

That's not really possible with CSS. You can use the :active pseudo element to possible some of what you want, but, if you try that out, you'll quickly see why it doesn't work.

You'll need to use JavaScript or jQuery to accomplish it.

Comment: No Offense, but it is possible. See: http://tangledindesign.com/how-to-trigger-css3-transitions-on-click-using-target/

Answer (score -1):

Try this example,

**HTML**

```
<img src="graphics/blue1.jpg" id="imgs" onclick="zoom()" alt= "" width="100" height="150" />
```

**JS**

```
function zoom(){
    var NAME = document.getElementById("imgs");

    if (menu == 1) {

        menu = 0;
        $("#imgs").animate(
            {'width': '150px','height':'250px'},150
        );

    } else {
        $("#imgs").animate(
            {'width': '100px','height':'150px'},150
        );
    }
}
```